# Why is my mock set empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am just starting to learn about unit testing and mocking. I've spent all day reading different tutorials, trying to find the best one to practice with. I've settled on [Testing with a mocking framework (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) as it is using EF6 (modern), as well as what seems to be a very popular mocking framework (Moq). Also, it is quite vanilla and hosted on the MSDN webset. It has to be decent, right?

I've set up a project exactly as specified in the example and am running the debugger through the test examples to make sure I understand what is going on. The test I'm working through is as follows:

```
[TestClass] 
public class QueryTests 
{ 
    [TestMethod] 
    public void GetAllBlogs_orders_by_name() 
    { 
        var data = new List<Blog> 
        { 
            new Blog { Name = "BBB" }, 
            new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" }, 
            new Blog { Name = "AAA" }, 
        }.AsQueryable(); 

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>(); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator()); 

        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>(); 
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object); 

        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object); 
        //test code here
        var blogs = service.GetAllBlogs(); 

        Assert.AreEqual(3, blogs.Count); 
        Assert.AreEqual("AAA", blogs[0].Name); 
        Assert.AreEqual("BBB", blogs[1].Name); 
        Assert.AreEqual("ZZZ", blogs[2].Name); 
    } 
}
```

It is very simple and I am lead to believe that I am understanding unit testing and the mocking framework. Cool! I decide to perform an experiment to validate myself, by inserting `service.AddBlog("ADO.NET Blog", "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet");` (from a previous example) into the above TestMethod, just after the service is instantiated.

I expect that as I step past `var blogs = service.GetAllBlogs();`, blogs should contain my new entry, but it does not. It only contains the 3 from the initialization of `data`.

What is going on here? Shouldn't that code insert a blog record into the `data` object, and thus pulling it when calling `GetAllBlogs()`? Perhaps I am not understanding the idea of mocks properly?

Comment: Mocking `DbSet<T>` is notoriously difficult. I would strongly recommend using either the repository pattern and testing the repositories or combine the repository pattern with an in-memory database which you can achieve easily using Effort. More on the latter technique on [my blog](http://www.vannevel.net/2015/02/26/11/). I highly discourage trying to mock everything EF related because it will turn your code into spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my mock set empty?

Because you didn't configure (*setup*) it to take any action when you insert data to it. When a mock is created it "loses" all the logic that was present on the original class and marked `virtual`. Moq simply overrides such methods so that later you can configure them to do anything (return value, throw, etc).

Naturally, you can setup `Add` method to insert data back to your `data` blog list:

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
mockSet.Setup(m => m.Add<It.IsAny<Blog>()).Callback(blog => data.Add(blog));
```

When `Add` method will be invoked on your `DbSet` (preferrably via call to service) *configured* version of `Add` will take over and insert blog to your data list (`Callback` method tells Moq to *"invoke this code"* when mocked method is called).

You could also try to prevent overriding of `Add` by using [CallBase](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior) parameter. However, this might not work as your DbSet is not aware of `list` existence, you'll most likely have to configure it more heavily then.

On a final note, once your experiment crystallizes you should realize that configuring `Add` won't be necessary because you won't be checking whether blog was added via `GetAllBlogs` method but rather by verification on the mock itself:

```
mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Blog>()), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Interesting... I suppose that makes sense, and that perhaps I am misunderstanding the idea/purpose of mock as suspected. Would you care to elaborate on the purpose of mocking then? It seems that all I am doing is checking to see if `Add` was actually called on a `Blog` object. Maybe it's due to the simplicity of the example, but it doesn't seem like a very valuable test. I am open to reference links as well.

Comment: @Jeff: Your idea of mocking is +/- correct. As far as `GetAllBlogs` test is concerned what you are doing is more or less correct. Naturally, the level of details during verification might be different (after all, you will be checking objects which you have just created 2 lines above) -- you can assert on list reference, list's count, each list element reference, etc. `AddBlog` on the other hand (probably) doesn't return anything and its "job" is not visible to outside world -- this is why you assert via `Verify` methods, which is natural approach in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use CallBase property?

```
mockSet.CallBase = true;
```